# What's the proper way to provide proofs of payments for citations in the N-400 (Application for Naturalization Form)?

Tags: usa, citizenship, paperwork, payment

In the N400 application or at USCIS naturalization interview, how to prove one has paid one's traffic tickets? Bank statements? Does the DMV provide proof of payment?

---

From the [Form N-400 Instructions](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/n-400instr.pdf):

> You do not need to submit documentation for traffic fines or incidents that  did not involve an arrest or did not involve drugs or alcohol, if the only penalty was a fine of less than $500 or points on your driving record.

Comment: If this is an actual problem that you face, then ask them what they would like to see for proof.

Comment: Is there some information somewhere that suggests that you will be asked (or might be asked) to prove that you've paid the tickets?

Comment: @phoog [Does one have to bring documents at the naturalization interview showing that one has paid one's traffic tickets, if traffic tickets were below $500?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/24099/164)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should obtain the proof from the court with the local jurisdiction (it should be listed on the ticket). If in doubt - contact the law enforcement department issuing the ticket.

Comment: Would a cancelled check not suffice?

Comment: @phoog I don't know. An explicit statement from the court would, for sure.