# Does one have to bring documents at the naturalization interview showing that one has paid one's traffic tickets, if traffic tickets were below $500?

Tags: usa, citizenship, paperwork, driving

From the [Form N-400 Instructions](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/n-400instr.pdf):

> You do not need to submit documentation for traffic fines or incidents that did not involve an arrest or did not involve drugs or alcohol, if the only penalty was a fine of less than $500 or points on your driving record.

It doesn't mention the interview.

I read on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIoscaodUTo&lc=Ugxcwen3mYZml45-6254AaABAg:

> - salla diallo: I had 2 traffic tickets that I already took her off and they were less than $500. Can I just explain that to the officer once I am scheduled for an interview?
> - USCitizenshipTest.Org: Yes. but make sure to bring some documents to show that you took care of them. Some Officers are stricter than others, so just be prepared.

Does one have to bring [documents](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/23998/164) at the naturalization interview showing that one has paid one's traffic tickets, if the traffic tickets were below 500 USD?

Answer (score 0):

One **has to** bring documents to the naturalization interview that are explicitly listed in the invitation to that said interview.

If one *wants to* bring additional documents because one anticipates potential questions from the officer during the interview and wants to be proactively ready - one is most certainly allowed to do so.

Whether and when the documents showing that *you* paid your below $500 traffic tickets would be required for *you* depends on the USCIS officer handling *your* case. As written in the quote you put in your question - `Some Officers are stricter than others, so just be prepared`.